# Increase counter inside IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have the following situation:

```cs
//IMemoryCache is injected into class and into field _cache
public void IncreaseCounter(string key){

     int currectCount = _cache.Get<int>(key) + 1;
     _cache.Set<int>(key, currentCount);
}
```

However I am aware that this is not the best method to do it. I would also like to check if the key **does exist**, if it does not, the counter should be `0` and then increased to `1`.

How would I do this ? I know of the method `GetOrCreate(object, Func<>)` but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetOrCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) basically works like this:

```
   int currentCount = _cache.GetOrCreate(key, _ => 0); // pass key and 
                                                       // "new item factory"
   // now, if key exists, it will return the cached value
   // if it does not exist, it will 
   // - create a new entry,
   // - execute the passed-in factory function und set the returned value in cache,
   // - return the result of the passed-in factory
   _cache.Set(key, currentCount+1);
```

The expected factory must be a `Func<ICacheEntry, TItem>` which translate to delegate of this form: `TItem FunctionName(ICacheEntry entry)`. So, a function that takes a parameter of type [`ICacheEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.icacheentry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and returns whatever type your values shall be.

`_ => 0` matches this in that it is a Func, that ignores the input param and just returns 0, which should be enough for the use case from the question.

See an [Example in Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eSt4CP)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        object key = new object();
        
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", cache.TryGetValue(key, out int val)?val:"key not found");
        
        Incr(key, cache);
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(key));
        
        Incr(key, cache);
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(key));
    }
    
    public static void Incr(object key, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        int currentValue = cache.GetOrCreate(key, _ => 0);
        cache.Set(key, currentValue+1);
    }
}
```

Produces

```
key not found
1
2
```

---

Just for your information - not relevant to the specific use case in question:

Mind that I used the "ignore" ( `_ =>`  ) here. If you need to, you can actually use information from the newly created cache entry from within the factory (or set values on it):

```
int currentValue = cache.GetOrCreate(key, entry => DoDBLookup(entry.Key));
```

for example, if you wanted to read-through to a database. Or set expiry, compute intial value based on key, etc ...

Comment: Your GetOrCreate approach did not work for me. The retrieved value (for the same key) is always 0.

Comment: You can update your question with your attempt to use it and we'll figure it out.